# Difference between 8086 and x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am starting to learn assembly language and totally confused about the processor family.Is 8086 and x86 both denote the architecture of the processor? I really need a start here.

Comment: 8086 is the old 16 bit-only cpu, from which current processors evolved. x86 is the general name for the whole family, but rarely used to refer to anything before the 386. The 64 bit versions are sometimes also included, or can be explicitly named as x86-64 (among other things).

Comment: Thanks.If so which is an eg for 32 bit CPU?

Comment: Anything after (and including) the 80386 is at least 32 bit, so 80486, Pentium family, Core family, etc. You can easily find this information on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86).

Comment: The first 32 bit CPU in that family is the 80386, which is why x86 is only rarely used to refer to the 80286.

Comment: One more doubt... Does the assembly language for the processors differ?? ie : Intel and AMD , x16 and x32

Comment: No, but different models (even from the same manufacturer) might support different set of instructions such as SSE or AVX. They all support the basic stuff, though. The details of the  assembly language syntax do depend on your assembler. 16 bit mode uses different addressing.

Answer (score 2):

8086 was the first processor in the x86 line and appeared around 1977.
Followed up by the 8088 in 1979 that formed the basis of the IBM-XT desktops.

Comment: Sort of. It followed the 8080 which followed the 8008 which followed the 4004. And those shared a common assembly language heritage.

Comment: @MSalters 8088 and predecessors had a different design and instruction set and are not part of x86 family.

Comment: They absolutely did not! The 8088 even had the **exact** same ISA. It's the cheaper version of the 8086, with an 8 bit databus to reduce the external pin count.

Comment: @MSalters I meant *8080* & predecessors. As I stated in my answer 8088 was a successor of 8086

Comment: @MSalters adding a hyperlink to credible source of those historic facts might resolve the dispute. Wikipedia seems insufficient

Comment: Straight from the source: (8086 Family User Manual, Intel 1979) : "The 8086 and 8088 are third-generation central processing units (CPU's) that differ primarily in their external data paths" (page 1-2). "Software written for one CPU will execute on the other without alteration"(page 2-1).